# How to prevent aborted async requests from corrupting state with watchEffect()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, fetch-api, vue-composition-api

Say we have a component that receives the ID of a resource through a prop, `resourceId`.  The component should fetch the corresponding resource from an API and display it, while also handling loading/error states (following a pattern similar to [this one](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation)).

The function that fetches the resource from the external API also returns an `abort` function which, if called, causes the request to immediately reject. When `resourceId` changes, any in-flight requests should be aborted in favor of a new request. For what it's worth, I'm using `fetch()` and `AbortController` for this.

Using Vue 3 with the composition API, I came up with an implementation that looks something like this:

```js
const loading = ref(false);
const data = ref(null);
const error = ref(null);

watchEffect(async (onCancel) => {
    loading.value = true;
    data.value = error.value = null;

    const { response, abort } = fetchResourceFromApi(props.resourceId);
    onCancel(abort);

    try {
        data.value = await (await response).json();
    } catch (e) {
        error.value = e;
    } finally {
        loading.value = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
<div v-else-if="error">Error: {{ error }}</div>
<div v-else>{{ data }}</div>
```

This works fine under most circumstances, but breaks whenever the cancellation comes in to play. If `resourceId` changes before the last API request has finished, the following order of events happens:

1. `abort()` gets called
2. `watchEffect` callback gets called, setting `loading`, `error`, and `data`
3. `catch` and `finally` blocks from original request are called, setting `loading` and `error`
4. Second API request completes and sets `loading` and `data`

This results in an unexpected state where `loading` is set to `false` while the second request is in flight, `error` contains the exception raised by aborting the first request, and `data` contains the value from the second request.

Are there any design patterns or workarounds that can deal with this problem?

Comment: The algorithm is the same as with generic loading indicator. `loading` state needs to be true if there's at least 1 pending request. Since there can be parallel requests, it needs to be computed from pending request count.

Comment: @Ryan Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @EstusFlask `loading` should only be true if the most recent request is in flight, and that also doesn't address the `error` problem.

Comment: I just resolved a very similar issue at work. I did it by passing the AbortSignal.signal from the component, all the way to the actual fetch-request's `signal`-option. I also had a state variable named `pendingFetches`, which I pushed some uuids in before any `await someApiCall(data, signal)` calls. After the await line, I just removed the corresponding id from the `pendingFetches` array - didn't matter how (abort, success, ...) and when the await returned, it just worked. Then in the render part I just had `if(pendingFetches.length > 0) { loading }` This did also solve that most recent issue

Answer (score 3):

if the sequence of events is as you described:

1. first `watchEffect`
2. `abort`
3. second `watchEffect`
4. catch and finally of the first `watchEffect`

Then you can keep a counter and use it to track what the current in flight request is (effectively it is a request id, or version as some libraries call it). Every time `watchEffect` is called, increase the counter and take a snapshot of the current value. Check in your catch and finally block if the present counter is the same as the counter value you started with. In case they mismatch, it means you are handling stale request errors so you can skip the modification of error and loading status.

```js
const {ref, watchEffect} = Vue;

const App = {
  setup() {
    const resourceId = ref(0);
    const loading = ref(false);
    const data = ref(null);
    const error = ref(null);

    // fake an api fetch method to asynchronously return 
    // a result after 3 seconds.
    const fetchFor = (id) => {
      let abort;
      const response = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        abort = () => reject(`request ${id} aborted`);
        setTimeout(() => resolve({msg: "result for " + id}), 3000);
      });
      return {response, abort};
    };


    let version = 0;

    watchEffect(async (onCancel) => {
      version ++;
      const currentVersion = version;
      
      loading.value = true;
      data.value = error.value = null;
      const { response, abort } = fetchFor(resourceId.value);
      onCancel(abort);
      try {
        data.value = await response;
      } catch (e) {
        if (currentVersion === version) {
          error.value = e;
        }
        
      } finally {
        if (currentVersion === version) {
          loading.value = false;
        }
      }
    });

    return {resourceId, loading, data, error};
  }
};
   
const app = Vue.createApp(App);
app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
 <button @click="resourceId++">Request</button>
 <div> last request is {{resourceId}} </div>
 <div> loading = {{loading}} </div>
 <div> data = {{data?.msg}} </div>
 <div> error = {{error}} </div>
</div>
```